# While coding a delete function in CRUD Angular app, why does a compilation error show property _id doesn't exist in array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

While working on MEAN app with Angular, the compiler seems to show error if I directly work on the array using the `this`keyword.

For instance, 
the code below returns a compilation error.

```
deleteTodo(todo) {
    this.todoService.deleteTodo(todo._id)
        .map(res => res.json)
        .subscribe( data => {
            for(var i=0 ; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
                if(this.todos[i]._id == todo._id)
                    this.todos.splice(i, 1);
            }
    });
}
```

The error says _id not defined in Todo type

Todo.ts

```
export class Todo{
  text: string;
  isCompleted: boolean;
}
```

Code for todos.component.ts is linked here: https://github.com/ajayns/angular-projects/blob/master/mean-todo/src/app/todos/todos.component.ts

Comment: does adding the type in function like this `deleteTodo(todo: Todo)` fix it? if no, can you share your `Todo class`?

Comment: @adiga the error seems to be with the array `todos` rather than the todo passed as argument.

Comment: export class Todo{
 text: string;
 isCompleted: boolean;
}

Comment: well you don't have an `_id` property in your `Todo class`, and the error is valid.

Comment: try adding `_id?: any;` and in your api code, just delete `_id` from `req.body` then all work fine

Comment: @Sravan  `_id?` can only be used in interfaces where variables can be optional right? Is it possible to use them in a class?

Comment: even if `?` is not there  just delete the `_id` from request in backend

Comment: also, check if `?` can be given to a class

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Todo{
  _id: string;
  text: string;
  isCompleted: boolean;
}
```

You missed the _id property

Comment: Isn't _id of type 'Objectid' though? and I thought it was managed automatically by the backend MongoDB and doesn't need to be specified in the frontend Angular../

Comment: Mongo add the id itself to the databse but in the front end you need to add it to the class if you want to access to it. String works, anyways all ids are just strings.

Comment: I added the code for the whole component. Thing is when I add such a property to the class, it brings up more errors. For instance while saving a new object, the id was left blank, now cause it's specified in the class, it returns an unspecified error. And it's only specified in the backend by mongodb @Elanochecer

Comment: Are you working on MEAN or just on Angular? I mean, do you have client and server parts of your app?

Comment: It's a project on MEAN stack. @elanochecer

Comment: Then you have to add the id just on the client side, not in the server side.